# WebBrowser/Navegador em Java

Tags: java

Como eu coloco uma espécie de um 'WebBrowser[.NET]' em um projeto em Java?

Sei que há motores de renderização livres como o Gecko, o qual é utilizado no Firefox. Porém não sei nem por onde começar, mesmo pegando um motor livre e pronto.

Queria uma luz de algum de vocês que saiba fazer isso. Procurei por vários tutoriais por aí de como fazer isso, mas nenhum resolveu meu problema!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249/is-there-a-way-to-embed-a-browser-in-java

Comment: Swing, SWT, JavaFX?

Comment: Queria, se possivel, em java swing!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nickolas, não sei se é isso que você precisa, mas me parece que sim.

O JavaFX fornece um componente chamado WebView  , que com a ajuda de WebEngine  pode ser usado para carregar páginas da Web junto com a construção do DOM e executar o JavaScript necessário.
Para aplicações Swing ele fornece outro componente chamado JFXPanel  que pode ser usado para incorporar componentes do JavaFX em aplicações Swing e por sua vez o JFXPanel é adicionado ao JFrame ou outros recipientes Swing.

Esse exemplo ai embaixo retirado do site http://www.javabeat.net/embedding-html-into-java-swing-applications/ pode ser exatamente o que você precisa.

[image: WebView]

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class SwingHtmlDemo {
  public static void main(String [] args){

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
      public void run() {
        ApplicationFrame mainFrame = new ApplicationFrame();
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
      }
    });

  }

}

/**
* Main window used to display some HTML content.
*/
class ApplicationFrame extends JFrame{

  JFXPanel javafxPanel;
  WebView webComponent;
  JPanel mainPanel;

  JTextField urlField;
  JButton goButton;

  public ApplicationFrame(){

    javafxPanel = new JFXPanel();

    initSwingComponents();

    loadJavaFXScene();
  }

  /**
  * Instantiate the Swing compoents to be used
  */
  private void initSwingComponents(){
    mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    mainPanel.add(javafxPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JPanel urlPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    urlField = new JTextField();
    urlField.setColumns(50);
    urlPanel.add(urlField);
    goButton = new JButton("Go");

    /**
     * Handling the loading of new URL, when the user
     * enters the URL and clicks on Go button.
     */
    goButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            String url = urlField.getText();
            if ( url != null && url.length() > 0){
                webComponent.getEngine().load(url);
            }
          }
        });

      }
    });

    urlPanel.add(goButton);
    mainPanel.add(urlPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    this.add(mainPanel);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(700,600);
  }

  /**
  * Instantiate the JavaFX Components in
  * the JavaFX Application Thread.
  */
  private void loadJavaFXScene(){
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        webComponent = new WebView();

        webComponent.getEngine().load("http://google.com/");

        borderPane.setCenter(webComponent);
        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane,450,450);
        javafxPanel.setScene(scene);

      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: E em swing, tem algum?

Comment: @NickolasCarlos Em swing "puro" não sei lhe dizer e até pesquisei para saber, mas pelo que via  solução é este JFXPanel mesmo, e coo pôde ver no código ele é 100% compatível com swing e de facil implementação...tente usar, quem sabe supre as suas necessidades numa boa.

Answer (score 0):

**Isso não responde a pergunta**, é uma resposta adicional para quem procura algo que use `javascript` mas como muita gente vai encontrar isso no Google está procurando uma forma de **automatizar por linha de comando** um navegador completo, tipo WebKit, é interessante considerar o [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).

O `PhamtomJS` tem versão para Windows, Linux e Windows, e, nas situações aonde é necessário mais do que simples web scrapping, ele é muito bom. Permite literalmente emular um navegador completo, tirar print screen e outras coisas.

O código abaixo, por exemplo, acessa o SOPT e tira um screenshot e salva na pasta local

```
// $ phantomjs nomedoarquivo.js
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://pt.stackoverflow.com/', function() {
  page.render('sopt.png');
  phantom.exit();
});
```